# Ubuntu sudden crash - Cache_Error

Tags: cache

I was drawing svg in a text editor when, suddenly, Ubuntu 13.04 crashed on me displaying a few lines, similar to each other. Here are the two first :

```
[30714.772014] nouveau E[     1265] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000
[30714.772321] nouveau E[    PFIF0] CACHE_ERROR -- Ch 1/4 Mthd 0x012c Data 0x00000000
```

The next four were almost the same as the second one, with a few numbers changing. Could someone tell me why this happened and how to stop it from happening again?

Comment: hardware specs ???

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a driver bug - see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-quantal/+bug/1097178

Comment: see workaround : http://askubuntu.com/questions/772021/xenial-16-04-crashes-with-nouveau-cache-error/862730#862730