# Xenial 16.04 crashes with nouveau CACHE_ERROR

Tags: drivers, nouveau

Video locked up completely.  Mouse wouldn't move, CTL-ALT-F1 wouldn't switch to emergency backup console.  Logged in via putty; from that login, the system seemed to be running normally, but nothing would unwedge the display, including unity --replace

I gave up and rebooted, but the reboot process never changed the display; I had to power cycle the system.

dmsg -T printed messages like this one; they were in syslog after the power cycle.

May 13 13:18:20 desktop kernel: [185318.986092] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: CACHE_ERROR - ch 9 [firefox[24095]] subc 5 mthd 0180 data beef0301

(All things being equal, I'd just as soon use the open source software, but I just switched to the Nvidia proprietary drivers per the instructions here:  [Install Nvidia driver instead nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau))

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error on fedora 25 - sometimes with chrome, and much more frequently with the webkit based native/default web browser.

The video display, mouse, keyboard would all freeze, but the ssh login would work - allowing one to see the nouveau cache errors in dmesg.

I tried a few arguments from https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/KernelModuleParameters/ , and developed the following workaround:

Add  nouveau.nofbaccel=1 to the Linux kernel line during booting.  On fedora it can be done by making changes to `/etc/default/grub` so that a line similar to this exists: 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="verbose nouveau.nofbaccel=1"

After this, install this command line  using grub mkconfig:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Reboot - preferably manually inspect that the command line has the flag.

After this change, the performance is a bit worse - but hardware acceleration is still detected by desktop manager - hence it works in full graphics mode.

Can you try this command line flag on Ubuntu boot on the line which specifies the Linux kernel to load.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried nouveau.nofbaccel=1 for serveral weeks with no improvement but found the variation below has been stable for 24 hours!

Your millage may vary :-)

nouveau.noaccel=1